# Problemas ao carregar imagem por css

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho uma biblioteca, no original estava da seguinte forma. O arquivo .css estava no raiz, e havia uma pasta chamada images que o css busca assim: /images/imagem.png. Bem, tivemos que fazer uma melhoria nessa biblioteca. Entã foi criado a pasta css, a pasta js e a pasta images. Montamos a seguinte estrutura de pasta:

> gen/modal/viewerPDF/js
>
> gen/modal/viewerPDF/css
>
> gen/modal/viewerPDF/images
>
> gen/modal/viewerPDF/viewer.html

Veja que o arquivo html, que é o principal, ficou na raiz da pasta principal do viewer. Bem, o que acontece que o css monta, senão o viewer estaria tudo bagunçado e não está, mas dá muitos erros, do qual posto um dos erros aqui. Resolvendo um resolvo os demais. O erro abaixo:

> http://10.104.33.247/gen/modal/viewerPDF/css/images/toolbarButton-viewThumbnail.png
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Observando a url montada, não existe. Não existe isso:

> ...css/images....

No css para pegar as imagens eu fiz:

```
content: url(images/secondaryToolbarButton-documentProperties@2x.png);
content: url(../images/secondaryToolbarButton-documentProperties@2x.png);
content: url(~/images/secondaryToolbarButton-documentProperties@2x.png);
```

E mesmo assim continua os erros citados demonstrados no devtools do Chrome. Como eu resolvo isso?

Esse é o header da página que chama o css e js:

```
<html dir="ltr" mozdisallowselectionprint moznomarginboxes>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
    <title>PDF.js viewer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/viewer.css"/>

    <!--<script src="compatibility.js"></script>-->

<!-- This snippet is used in production (included from viewer.html) -->
<!--<link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="locale/locale.properties"/>-->
<script src="js/l10n.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdf.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="debugger.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/viewer.js"></script>

  </head>
```

Comment: Poderia postar a estrutura de diretorios? O local onde chama o CSS e o local onde ele realmente esta, e o local onde as imagens estão?

Comment: @HiagoSouza, fiz uma edição e postei o header onde estão as chamadas dos arquivos css e js. A estrutura de diretório é a que eu pus no primeiro post.

Comment: Passa o LINK da página `viewer.html`. Tentei isso mas não carrega: http://10.104.33.247/gen/modal/viewerPDF/viewer.html

Comment: Eu reiniciei o comp e funcionou. Estou tendo muitos problemas com cache no chrome, quando eu altero qualquer javascript. E só consigo descarregar com um reboot. E isso é um incômodo para quem desenvolve. O postado acima é como está hoje e no css para pegar as imagens fiz assim: content: url(../images/toolbarButton-secondaryToolbarToggle@2x.png);

Comment: @pnet pode parecer uma pergunta boba mas, você desabilitou o cache no console do chrome? Isso facilita bastante

Comment: Dessa forma também não funciona: 
content: url(/gen/modal/viewerPDF/images/secondaryToolbarButton-documentProperties@2x.png);
??